# URL fragment in links and ajax redirects in JSF

Tags: ajax, url, jsf, redirect, jsf-2

I found out that methods called by ajax actions in JSF 2.0 can return navigation case and then the page can be redirected.

Eg. when I am on page `index.xhtml` and my ajax call return navigation case `detail` then the page is redirected. That is great.

```
 <h:commandLink value="The link" action="#{bean.someAction}" >
            <f:ajax />
 </h:commandLink>
```

But now I would like to do only partial redirect in the current page, so I would like to use URL fragment. The desired final URL looks like this `index.xhtml#someComponentId`. I have tried to do it with appending of `#fragment` part behind the navigation case but it doesn't work.

Is there any way how to make ajax and normal redirects able to use URL fragments, please? Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify fragments all day in your code but you have nothing to parse those fragments.  Your going to need more control over your page.  I have used the jQuery hashchange plugin briefly.  http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/.  There is also a plugin called BBQ, which is on the same page and does more.

Your then going to need to specify a callback(there are tutorials on that site I gave you) to direct the page what to do on that particular hash.

Check out the examples.

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/

I know this answer is kind of vague but I believe it will point you in the correct direction on how to solve this issue.